# When is static friction dissipative and when it is non-dissipative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction, rigid-body-dynamics, dissipation

In some cases, like in pure rolling, static friction is non-dissipative in nature. So, how can we identify when is static friction dissipative or non-disspative?

Comment: Do you have an example of dissipative static friction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static friction means the points of two bodies in contact do not move with respect to each other. Forces are opposite (due to 3rd law) but velocities are the same, so work done on body 1 is minus work done on body 2. So there cannot be any dissipation, all work manifests as change of mechanical energy. One could argue that perfect static friction isn't really friction, but pushing via mechanical contact.

Answer (score 1):

Static friction is non-dissipative because there is no relative motion at the point of contact between the involved surfaces. For pure rolling the point of contact between to two surfaces keeps changing, so that there is no relative motion between the surfaces at that point.

Hope this helps.